# UITableView animation not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

```
table.beginUpdates()
array.removeLast()
table.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([anIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None) 
for object in container {  
   array.append(object)
}
array.append("New Object") 
table.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([Set of IndexPaths]), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade) 
table.endUpdates()
```

I am using the above code. It works fine, but the only problem is the animation. After execution of above lines of code, table view scroll position is set to top. Not sure how. Thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Are you using `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight` method on your controller ? I had the same problem before with that method.

Comment: Are you facing this issue only in iOS 8?

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb my application support only iOS 9+

Comment: @TapasPal are you doing this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

If you post your complete code related only to this. We can fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before setting this attribute : `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight`

If you are using that, please try to add this method on your controller to prevent this kind of disappointment.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: This could be the solution only if he is using AutomaticDimension.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with you. I had this kind of problem. If he doesn't use estimatedHeightForRow I can't help him..

Comment: I ama using the same. table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
table.estimatedRowHeight = 500.0

Comment: Try by adding the method above

Comment: then what will be `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?